# Why is destructor of boost::thread detaching joinable thread instead of calling terminate() as standard suggests?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost-thread, standards-compliance

According to the draft C++0x standard, this code:

```
void simplethread()
{
    boost::thread t(someLongRunningFunction);
    // Commented out detach - terminate() expected.
    // t.detach();  
}
```

... should result in an terminate() call, but in current (boost 1.46.1) implementation of boost threads it doesn't, thread simply gets detached in destructor and continues on.

My question is: why?

I thought boost::thread is as much inline with draft standard as it gets.

Is there a design reason for this? 
Will it be changed in future versions of boost::thread?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508181/thread-destructors-in-c0x-vs-boost

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason is largely historical.  `boost::thread` came first.  The proposals for `std::thread` were derived from `boost::thread` and originally had the behavior that `boost::thread` does now.

However during the standardization process a significant number of people wanted `std::thread::~thread()` to `join()` in the destructor if not already joined, instead of `detach()`.  The arguments were made for each side and the votes were taken.  50/50.  More arguments were made and more votes were taken.  Some people were swayed to the other position.  But still 50/50.

Someone (I don't recall who) suggested `terminate()`.  Votes were taken and though it wasn't unanimous in favor (I couldn't vote for it), it did receive enough of a majority to be called consensus.

I imagine `boost::thread` never changed because it had an installed user base and no one wants to unnecessarily break code for that user base.

**Edit:**

Ah, Rob points us to the original of this duplicate question and that
answer points to [N2802](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2802.html) which includes rationale.

I should also note that the original proposal for `std::thread` had thread cancellation, and ~thread() would cancel the unjoined-thread and then detach it, which made a lot of sense.  This code path would normally only be chosen when the parent thread was unwinding due to an exception.