# mutex destroyed while busy

Tags: multithreading, c++11

There is a singleton object of EventHandler class to receive events from the mainthread. It registers the input to a vector and creates a thread that runs a lambda function that waits for some time before deleting the input from the vector to prevent repeated execution of the event for this input for some time.

But I'm getting mutex destroyed while busy error. I'm not sure where it happened and how it happened. I am not even sure what it meant either because it shouldn't be de-constructed ever as a singleton object. Some help would be appreciated.

```
class EventHandler{
public:
    std::mutex simpleLock;
    std::vector<UInt32> stuff;
    void RegisterBlock(UInt32 input){
        stuff.push_back(input);
        std::thread removalCallBack([&](UInt32 input){
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
            simpleLock.lock();
            auto it = Find(stuff, input);
            if (it != stuff.end())
                stuff.erase(it);
            simpleLock.simpleLock.unlock();
        }, input)
        removalCallBack.detach();
    }
    virtual EventResult ReceiveEvent(UInt32 input){
            simpleLock.lock();
            if (Find(stuff, input) != stuff.end()){
                RegisterBlock(input));
                //dostuff
            }
            simpleLock.simpleLock.unlock();
    }
};
```

Comment: You should consider using lock_guard instead of directly locking and unlocking the mutex. If the "mutex destroyed while busy" is reproducible, you should check in a debugger where it happens.

Comment: Yea, my existing code actually uses lock_guard.

Answer (score 7):

What is happening is that a thread is created

```
std::thread removalCallBack([&](UInt32 input){
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
   simpleLock.lock();
   ...
removalCallBack.detach();
```

And then since ***removalCallBack*** is a local variable to the function ***RegisterBlock***, when the function exits, the destructor for  ***removalCallBack*** gets called which invokes ***std::terminate()***

> [Documentation for thread destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread)
>
> ~thread(); (since C++11)
>
> Destroys the thread object. If *this still has an associated running thread (i.e. joinable() == true), std::terminate() is called.

but depending on timing, ***simpleLock*** is still owned by the thread (is busy) when the thread exits which according to the spec leads to undefined behavior, in your case the *destroyed while busy* error.

To avoid this error, you should either allow the thread to exist after the function exits (e.g. not make it a local variable) or block until the thread exits before the function exits using ***thread::join***

Dealing with cleaning up after threads can be tricky especially if they are essentially used as different programs occupying the same address space, and in those cases many times a *manager* thread just like you thought of is created whose only job is to reclaim thread related resources.  Your situation is a little easier because of the simplicity of the work done in the thread created by ***removalCallBack***, but there still is cleanup to do.

If the thread object is going to be created by new, then although system resources used by the system thread the C++ thread object represents will get cleaned up, but the memory the object uses will remain allocated until delete is called.

Also, consider if the program exits while there are threads running, then the threads will be terminated, but if there is a mutex locked when that happens, once again there will be undefined behavior.

What is usually done to guarantee that a thread is no longer running is to join with it, but though [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) doesn't say, the pthread_join man page states

> Once a thread has been detached, it can't be joined with pthread_join(3) or be made joinable again.

Comment: I thought detaching it would be enough. Looks like I have to keep the thread object on a map and make another thread object to manage these thread objects :/

Comment: Not sure if I should start another question. I don't quite know how to test for memory leak so I'll just ask here. If I create this thread with new operator (thus it won't go out of scope like it does here), and detach it, which should make the thread object clean itself up on termination. Does that mean I don't have to keep track of it anywhere?
Okay I read some more stuff online. They say std::terminate() does not get called once detached. It continues to run after the object is destructed. How am I getting the error then?

Comment: @PuiHoLam I've updated the answer.  I think the documentation clearly indicates that ***terminate()*** will be called. Otherwise, as a practical matter, the alternative would lead to undefined behavior because the thread would be referenced through a destructed object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508181/thread-destructors-in-c0x-vs-boost
"This is indeed true, and this choice is explained in N3225 on a note regarding std::thread destructor :
If joinable() then terminate(), otherwise no effects."
It only terminate() if the thread is joinable. If detach() was called, joinable() returns false.
I found out what happened now. Please close this question. It was me being derp when refactoring the code. I forgot about a return in the middle of the function which exits the function before the lock is released.

Comment: Please accept the given answer as it seems to be a suitable solution.